# Rails Routes for Active Storage Get Blob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activestorage

My Active Storage uploads successfully but when I go to retrieve it locally I get the below error message.

What is the correct routing for local active storage blob retrieving?

`ERROR`

```
Could not find devise mapping for path "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBLdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--0e11bfcbbc94f3699c9f559ee5f293a09c43bcac/1200px-Goldman_Sachs.svg.png". This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

I tried adding these (but it didn't work):

```
get '/rails/active_storage/blobs/:id', to: 'active_storage/disk_controller#show'
get '/rails/active_storage/disk/:id', to: 'active_storage/disk_controller#show'
```

Comment: how you access the attachement?

Comment: How your routes look?